# Terminate called without an active exception : LeetCode Question 74

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program to search for an element in a 2D matrix. It's not giving me an active/named exception, but it just throws me a Runtime error.

Any help with as to why this is happening?

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
        for (int i=0 ;i< matrix.size(); ++i){
            int m = matrix[i].size() -1 ;
            int n = matrix.size()-1;
            if (matrix[n][m] < target){
                return false;
            }
            else if (matrix[i][m] < target){
                i++;
            } else {
                 for (int j=0;j <= m; j++ ){
                    if (matrix[i][j] == target){
                        return true;
                    } else if (matrix[i][j] != target) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                
                 if (matrix[i][m] != target ){
                    return false;
                }
            }      
        }throw; 
    }
};
```

Comment: What is `throw;` supposed to do? Don't use such sites to learn *anything*, that's not their purpose whatever you might have heard. If you want to learn C++ invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). If you want to learn programming in general, take computer-science classes and learn multiple languages.

Comment: `throw` is executed immediately after reaching exit from block it precedes ( slight oversight on cppreference's side  not to mention it)  . The message is just result of `throw` without arguments, it's meant to re-throw active  exception (in handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    }throw;
```

A `throw` without following expression can be used inside an exception handler to re-throw the currently handled exception.

However, at this point your program does not *have* an active exception. In this case, [`throw` calls `std::terminate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

This seems to be an edit artifact.